# QGIS not opening after update

Tags: qgis, c++, update, directx, dll

I installed/updated microsoft visual c++ 2013 and microsoft directX runtime 2013. After that, whenever i open qgis i get this

```
The program can't start because MSVCP120.dll is missing from your computer.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the MicroSoft installer got carried away cleaning up during the upgrade. I'm fairly sure that the QGis installer will add `MSVCP120.dll` if it is missing at install time so a simple QGis reinstall will fix the problem for you.